# "The most distant ever visited by a spacecraft from Earth"

Tags: grammaticality, comparisons

This is from the [transcript](http://www.scientificamerican.com/podcast/episode.cfm?id=find-an-asteroid-to-visit-11-06-25) of a podcast:

> Now, these pictures can be a bit messy. So scientists say they could use plenty of eyes to help scan the pics for things that move—the same way Tombaugh first found Pluto. **The winning object could become the most distant ever visited by a spacecraft from Earth.**

I can read the sentence in bold literally. But I think it supposed to be like this:

> The winning object could become the most distant **one that has been** ever visited by a spacecraft from Earth.

What is the grammar phenomenon in the sentence? And how should I understand it?

Comment: I think there is an implicit _object_ in the sentence: "The winning object could become the most distant **object** ever visited by a spacecraft from Earth."

Comment: The headline, _“The most distant ever visited by a spacecraft from Earth”_ is a fragment and cannot stand alone, but requires context as well as a verb (as it has in the actual quote).

Comment: Instead of "has been ever visited" I would prefer "has ever been visited".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called [ellipsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_%28linguistics%29).  Your interpretation of the sentence is, I believe, correct.

Comment: OP's interpretation of the meaning is indeed correct, but I think you should make the point that grammatically speaking the word being elided is simply **object**. OP's *"one that has been"* is a rephrasing that conveys the same sense, although it sounds odd to me unless you move the word *"ever"* back to before *"been"*.

Answer (score 4):

I think there is an implicit *object* in the sentence: "The winning object could become the most distant **object** ever visited by a spacecraft from Earth."

That is called *ellipsis*:

> the omission from speech or writing of a word or words that are superfluous or able to be understood from contextual clues.

**<sub>[Reference: the *New Oxford American Dictionary*.]</sub>**